# best way to query my database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I started working on a small project using Laravel, so i have three tables in my database

1. Products
2. Categories
3. Brands

i want to list all my product in a HTML table, right now i use in my controller this method **leftJoin** is that the correct way or i have to do that with eloquent if yes how give me an example

```
public function index()
{
    $query = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoin('categories','categories.id', '=', 'products.product_category')
    ->leftJoin('brands','brands.id', '=', 'products.product_brand')
    ->leftJoin('suppliers','suppliers.id', '=', 'products.product_supplier')
    ->orderBy('products.id', 'desc')->paginate(15);
    return response()->json($query);
}
```

This is my result :

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": null,
        "product_name": "Dylan Hernandez",
        "product_sell_as": "Delectus pariatur",
        "product_upc": 12541,
        "product_sku": "12541",
        "product_description": "Et enim quisquam ani",
        "product_category": 2,
        "product_supplier": 2,
        "product_buying_price": "390.00",
        "product_selling_price": "226.00",
        "product_min_stock": "10.00",
        "product_max_stock": "10.00",
        "product_alert_stock": 10,
        "product_alert_phone": "+1 (955) 289-5975",
        "product_alert_email": "mexi@mailinator.net",
        "product_cost_price": "145.00",
        "product_supplier_discount": "10.00",
        "product_uom": 2,
        "product_brand": 2,
        "product_warehouse": 2,
        "product_availability": 2,
        "product_image": "public/product/tDlkQkCZA4aWDnFkWIed8TKQEP0Wgu0zYGtYfD5T.jpeg",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "category_name": "Shoes",
        "brand_name": "Dolce Gabana",
        "supplier_company": null,
        "supplier_code": null,
        "supplier_tax_number": null,
        "supplier_phone": null,
        "supplier_fax": null,
        "supplier_website": null,
        "supplier_email": null,
        "supplier_note": null,
        "supplier_type": null,
        "supplier_address": null,
        "supplier_city": null,
        "supplier_state": null,
        "supplier_zip": null,
        "supplier_country": null,
        "supplier_representative": null,
        "supplier_price_list": null,
        "supplier_tax_type": null,
        "supplier_currency": null
    }
  ]
```

Comment: what kind of response structure do u want? and what's relationship between them

Comment: @TsaiKoga  i have updated my question ;)

Comment: if the `products` with `categories` is one-to-many, and `products` with `brand` is one-to-many, u can do it by relationship.

Comment: can you please give an example i'm new on laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Eloquent [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) will be elegant:

In your Category Model

```php
        public function products()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(\App\Product::class, 'product_category', 'id');
        }
```

In your Brand Model:

```php
        public function products()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(\App\Brand::class, 'brand', 'id');
        }
```

In your Supplier Model:

```php
        public function products()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(\App\Supplier::class, 'product_supplier', 'id');
        }
```

In your Product Model:

```php
        public function category()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\Category::class, 'product_category');
        }

        public function brand()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\Brand::class, 'brand');
        }  

        public function supplier()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(\App\Supplier::class, 'product_supplier');
        }
```

So you can query just like this:

```php
Product::with(['category', 'brand', 'supplier'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Thank you what about suppliers ?

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi It the same, you need to add relationship in model. Updated